# PHP login form not inserting user data

Tags: php

I am trying to get a simple login/register form to work but every time I try to test the register form, it does not save the data to PhpMyAdmin for some reason and keeps giving me an error. Here is my code if someone could figure it out. Would be a great help.

I don't know if it could be the $query and $res variables but I messed around with them and ended up getting a confirmation that the data has been saved but there was nothing in my mysql database.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ){
    header("Location: home.php");
}
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

$error = false;

if ( isset($_POST['btn-signup']) ) {

    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $name = strip_tags($name);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

    $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
    $pass = strip_tags($pass);
    $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);

    if (empty($name)) {
        $error = true;
        $nameError = "Please enter your full name.";
    } else if (strlen($name) < 3) {
        $error = true;
        $nameError = "Name must have atleat 3 characters.";
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
        $error = true;
        $nameError = "Name must contain alphabets and space.";
    }

    if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $error = true;
        $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
    } else {
        // check email exist or not
        $query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($count!=0){
            $error = true;
            $emailError = "Provided Email is already in use.";
        }
    }

    if (empty($pass)){
        $error = true;
        $passError = "Please enter password.";
    } else if(strlen($pass) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $passError = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } 

    $pass = hash('sha256', $pass);

    if( !$error ) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO users(first_name,email,password) VALUES('$name','$email','$pass')";
        $res = mysqli_query($query);

        if ($res) {
            $errTyp = "success";
            $errMSG = "Successfully registered, you may login now";
            unset($name);
            unset($email);
            unset($pass);
        } else {
            $errTyp = "danger";
            $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Heres my dbconnect.php if this could be the problem.

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'password';
$db = 'accounts';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);

try{
    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db}",$user,$pass);
    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars` when saving to the database. That should only be used when you're displaying data on a web page, to prevent XSS.

Comment: You should be using [PHPs password_hash lib](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate secure password hashes. It's very simple to do! You should also be using prepared and parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an argument to `mysqli_query()`:

```
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
```

It would also be better if you used a prepared statement and `bind_param` instead of substituting strings into the query.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(first_name,email,password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $pass);
$res = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: ``$stmt->bind_param("iii", $name, $email, $pass);`` should be ``$stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $pass);``

Comment: @ScarletHarlot What does `echo $stmt->error;` show?

Comment: it says "Field 'user_name' doesn't have a default value "

Comment: You need to fix your table schema to have a default for that column, or change your registration form to get the user's full name.

Comment: Yeah I think I just figured that out. Had other columns in database without making them NULL first before testing this script out. Haha that would of helped a lot and it works perfectly now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Why weren't you printing the error message before? Isn't that basic to debugging?

Comment: Still learning PHP so I didn't know to do that. Complete noob here